# Odoo loop in create

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have created the following nested loop that allows me to record the payment installments of each invoice, which works perfectly:

```
for num in range(1, int(dues)+1):
  for data1 in lista:
    new = Dues.create({
      're_customer': data1['cliente'][0],
      'amount_dues': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'amount_total': data1['cliente'][1],
      'number_dues': num,
      'n_invoice': data1['cliente'][2],
      'pay_amount_dues': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'debit_balance': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'day': []
    })
```

I am now working to add a `day` key to the dictionary passed to the `Dues.create()` method above.

Right now, I am trying to use the following to store all days in a variable:

```
for daysum in range(1, int(dues)+1):
  td = td + int(day)
  dias.append(td)
```

This accumulates the days in a list like this: `[12, 13, 31]`

Having done the above, I now need to figure out how to add each day of the list to the `day` key in the dictionary passed to the `Dues.create()` method above.

My goal is to save a single day in each `Dues.create()` method call, so the first time we call `Dues.create()` we pass 12 as the value of `day`, and the second time we call `Dues.create()` we pass 13 as the value of `day`, and so on. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: This question is not yet clear to me at least -- would you be able to try and rephrase what you're trying to do?

Comment: I can not register an arrangement in a field in odoo, because what I want is that element I have in my arrangement X = [1,2,3,4] that the days are created one by one in the cycle for that creates to create the registry in the data saes, if you observe it is a dictionary and there is a key called Day because there I must place each element of the arrangement example 1 or 4
where 1 or 4 are the day.
Do you understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried editing your question to replace some of the language that was there (like "cycle") with the traditional terms for the given concept (e.g. "cycle" = "loop"). Having done so, I think I understand a little bit more about your goals, but I'm still not quite sure.

You create one value in `dias` for each value in `range(1, int(dues)+1)`. Likewise, you use `range(1, int(dues)+1)` as the upper loop for your `Dues.create()` method calls. My hunch is that you may wish to use the index position `num - 1` in that loop to identify the value in `dias` that corresponds to the given `num` value. (Subtract one because your range uses 1-based indexing).

In other words, if I am understanding you, I think you want to create the `dias` variable first, then do:

```
for num in range(1, int(dues)+1):
  for data1 in lista:
    new = Dues.create({
      're_customer': data1['cliente'][0],
      'amount_dues': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'amount_total': data1['cliente'][1],
      'number_dues': num,
      'n_invoice': data1['cliente'][2],
      'pay_amount_dues': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'debit_balance': float(data1['cliente'][1]) / dues,
      'day': dias[num-1]
    })
```

If I have misunderstood you please feel free to follow up...

Comment: @jpozzo my pleasure